# Android Databinding for Custom View: 'cannot find symbol' and 'duplicate class found'

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have previously changed some code in my project and now there is the following error thrown during compilation for the following auto-generated class:

**DataBinderMapperImpl.java** : cannot find symbol "AdvancedBoxBindingImpl" (in line 'import ...databinding.AdvancedBoxBindingImpl;')

The AdvancedBox is included in the the layout **fragment_config.xml** like this:

```
<layout xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <variable name="viewModel" type ="...GlobalConfigViewModel"/>
    </data>
...
<....AdvancedBox
                android:id="@+id/advancedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:viewModel = "@{viewModel}"
                android:visibility="@{viewModel.advancedShown ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>
...
</layout>
```

The **advanced_box.xml** looks like this:

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="...GlobalConfigViewModel" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ....
```

The binding in the **AdvancedBox**-class is instantiated like this:

```
class AdvancedBox : LinearLayout{
    private lateinit var mBinding: AdvancedBoxBinding
    init{
        mBinding = AdvancedBoxBinding.inflate(inflater, this, true)
    }
```

All of this previously worked, but I have recently updated Android Studio and made changes in the Code.

Additional Information:

- gradle.properties has the attribute 'android.databinding.enableV2=true'
- I have tried File->Invalidate Caches and Restart

Any suggestions on what might be the problem?

Comment: Would you please try to delete the build folder and then clean build?

Answer (score 2):

Possible problem with the way data has been bound to the view.
In my case, I had a model :

```
<data>
    <variable name="user" type="zw.org.coop.models.User"/>
</data>
```

but because of copy pasting, I had a typo like :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fullName"
    style="@style/styleEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@{user.user.firstName}"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    tools:text="Dean Kaila" />
```

where **user.user.firstName** was not intended but **user.firstName**

Would've been better if **Jetbrains** had some *intellisense* going on to help with such issues, but yeah, that was a good 2 days for me.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

where have you specified the binding class inside xml? I think that's the issue

```
<layout>
    <data class="AdvancedBoxBinding">
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="...GlobalConfigViewModel" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```